# CMD Batch - I can't do this loop works

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Please help me finding the error. . . I'm trying to do a loop in a cmd batch. The loop should enter to a path (recursive) and count all the CSV files there, if there is no file, should exit and go to the same loop but for TXT files.

Every time I run . . . the first loop never stops

```
SET csvf=0
SET txtf=0

ECHO CSV. . . 
:CSVFILES
FOR %%A IN ('DIR "PATH\*.txt" /S') DO SET /A csvf+=1
IF %csvf% neq 0 (
    CALL :PYT
    CALL :CSVFILES
) ELSE (
    CALL :TXTFILES
)

ECHO TXT. . . 
:TXTFILES
FOR %%B IN ('DIR "PATH\*.txt" /S') DO SET /A txtf+=1
IF %txtf% neq 0 (
    CALL :PYT
    CALL :TXTFILES
) ELSE (
    EXIT
)

:PYT
%python3% ANOTHERPATH.py
EXIT /B
```

Comment: recursive calling is a bad idea. You will generate a stack overflow eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've quite understood what you're trying to achieve, so this is my best guess based upon the information you've provided. If my assessment is incorrect, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63084745/edit) to provide a better understanding of the task requirements.

You don't really need a count, you only need to know if there are any files, for this you can use the `where` command. This, with its `/Q` option, outputs an exit code as an errorlevel, *(`2` Invalid Source, `1` No Match, `0` Match)*. We can then check those errorlevels. If the `errorlevel` is `2`, we might as well end the script as the `%BasePath%` is an invalid source. If the `errorlevel` is `1` there are no `.txt` files, so we need to check for `.csv` files using the same method. Whenever the `errorlevel` is `0`, we can `call :PYT` and then loop again to the :`FileCheck`s. This essentially means that your code will continue to run, until there are no `.txt` and no `.csv` files anywhere within the `%BasePath%`

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "BasePath=C:\Users\Jose\test"

:FileCheck
SetLocal
Set "PATHEXT=" 
"%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /Q /R "%BasePath%" *.txt
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :EOF
If ErrorLevel 1 ("%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /Q /R "%BasePath%" *.csv
    If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo No txt or csv files found.
        "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /T 5 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        GoTo :EOF))
EndLocal
Call :PYT
GoTo FileCheck

:PYT
Rem Your code here
```

Comment: **¡THANKS! Compo** You are awesome . . . Could you recommend me a book or a blog for continue learning about batch.

Comment: @Jose - ss64.com has pretty much everything you'll need to start out